# Fetching and saving the date from Database in UTC

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to save and retrive the date in UTC.
Used the property in `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = UTC` in application properites.

---

Now the dates are getting saved in UTC, but when retrieving the value is getting converted to JVMs time zone. Is there any way to prevent this conversion? I want to retrieve the date time in UTC itself.

Comment: How are you determining that it's getting converted to the JVMs timezone?

Comment: @123 While fetching from the DB, then time is getting converted. Its not the same utc time as in the DB.

Comment: Yes but how are you deciding it has been converted, are you printing it a log?

Comment: @123 yes. I am printing in the logs. I wrote a simple get request and in response the time is not the same as in Db

Comment: Was able to solve this issue by using  ` @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }`

Comment: Nice one, glad you worked it out!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably configure your DB, to set UTC by default. 
I recommend you to read this [topic by Vlad Mihalcea](https://vladmihalcea.com/date-timestamp-jpa-hibernate/)